# Ruby on rails is mixing up with two parent relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 related objects: Group, Cipher, User.
Ciphers belong both to a group and to a user. Users also belong to a group directly.

The Group's Show view displays a Group with belonging Ciphers.
I wish to display the first name of the user who owns each cipher, but it raises the error  `undefined method 'first_name' for #<Group:0x007fa3f4a038a0>`

Here is the Show view extract:

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
      <tr align="left">
        <th><%= t('Cipher') %></th>
        <th><%= t('User') %></th>
        <th><%= t('EndOfLife') %></th>
        <th><%= t('UpdatedBy') %></th>
        <th><%= t('UpdatedAt') %></th>
      </tr>

      <% @group.ciphers.order("updated_at").each do |child_object| %>
      <tr align="left">
        <td valign="top"> <%=child_object.key%> </td>
        <td valign="top"> <%=child_object.user.first_name%> </td>
        <td valign="top"> <%=child_object.valid_until%> </td>
        <td valign="top"> <%=child_object.updated_by%> </td>
        <td valign="top"> <%=child_object.updated_at%> </td>
      </tr>
      <% end%>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Here is the group model:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :ciphers, :inverse_of => :user, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ciphers, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
```

Here is the cipher model:

```
class Cipher < ApplicationRecord
  #Filters
  before_save { self.cipher_hash = (BCrypt::Password.create(key+group.name)).split(//).last(32).join }

  #Validations
  validates :key, :valid_until, :group_id, :user_id, presence: true
  validates :key, length: {maximum: 100}

  #Relations
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here is the user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :zxcvbnable

  #Filters
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  #Validations
  validates :name, :first_name, :group_id, presence: true, length: {maximum: 100}

  #Relations
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :ciphers
end
```

Thanks for your help!
end

Comment: my i see the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> undefined method 'first_name' for Group:0x007fa3f4a038a0

By using `inverse_of`, you are setting a *bi-directional association* and since the `fisrt_name` *isn't available for the `Group`*, it spits out with that error.

***Solution:***

Just remove the `inverse_of`

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :ciphers, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ciphers, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Comment: You are right ! reverse_of should target the parent group, not the user !